# Is magical humanoid by-product allowed in restaurants by the FDA?

Tags: magic, government, mythical-creatures, food, law

What steps should a monster take to make good of their ability to create food, without getting shut down by the Food and Drug Administration in America? For instance, a dryad summoning her own leaves for tea, or a harpy using her unfertilized eggs for omelettes.

Monsters include all monsters from folklore, localized except where immigration thrives (A wave of Irish immigrants could also bring a wave of dullahan and fair folk). Monsters publicly exist, but anyone with citizenship is legally assumed to be human. Some monsters try to look human to blend in better.

**Some extra development of the scenario:**

- This is for a small business cafe in particular, with light to moderate traffic in the suburbs.
- Humanoid Monsters take up about seven percent of the population.
- The main character is a dryad skilled in her magic who is having trouble explaining to health inspectors how her plants are sustainably sourced and  thoroughly washed before use in teas and seasonings.
- Also, would this extend to non-food use such as werewolf fur sweaters or leatherwork lined in Naga scales? Who would be in charge of those jurisdictions if not the FDA?

Comment: "Is magical humanoid by-product allowed in restaurants by the FDA?" ... wha.. what??

Comment: @michaelgriffin what is confusing about it?

Comment: it's not confusing it just sounds insane lol. what even gave you this idea in the first place? the phrasing of the title makes it sound like you are asking "is human poop allowed by the fda?"

Comment: because i mixed up "by-product" with "excrement"

Comment: Right now I'm flashing on an episode from _Futurama_ where Fry learns the source of Slurm. "Honey comes out of a bee's behind!"

Comment: BTW, fun fact: most laws deal with "persons", not "humans". There are cases in which "thought entities" (e.g. a corporation) can be considered a "person" for legal purposes. If E.T. showed up tomorrow (or we create a true AI, or whatnot), it would probably be straight-forward to have him/her/it declared a legal person, with all the rights, privileges, responsibilities and liabilities thereof. "Anyone with citizenship is legally assumed to be human" is actually wrong; they'd be "persons", and they wouldn't even need citizenship.

Comment: @Matthew That's pretty interesting!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The harvesting and selling of a humaniod by-products sounds like it would fall under the U.S. Department of Agriculture’s Animal and Plant Health Inspection Service(**APHIS**). More specifically [*The Lacy Act*](https://thesustainabilityalliance.us/lacey-act/) which, "regulates the trade of wildlife and plants and creates penalties for violations."

While *The Lacy Act* doesn't cover bi-product distribution and consumption, they would definitely have some hand in making sure that things like "werewolf fur sweaters" are under regulation. For a dryad summoning her own leaves for tea, **APHIS** might perceive that as a [Plant Growth Enhancer](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/aphis/ourfocus/planthealth/import-information/permits/plant-pests/sa_plant-growth-enhancers/plant-growth-enhancers) in which they would need certain permits to use them in tea.

As far as something like a harpy's eggs being used, that's a tough one. The FDA does have a lot of regulations concerning [eggs](https://www.fda.gov/food/eggs-guidance-documents-regulatory-information/egg-safety-final-rule), but it concerns the handling and shipping of eggs so they don't develop 'Salmonella enteritidis'. So the FDA wouldn't have a huge problem with it as long as the laying conditions, handling, and storing is all up-to-code.

Answer (score 2):

Human food byproducts are actually ***nòt*** regulated by the FDA.

> Currently, the human milk market is self-regulated...
>
> Even though classifying human milk as a food, drug, or tissue would allow FDA to regulate suppliers...

[**The referenced article**](https://www.theregreview.org/2019/08/20/fritz-human-milk-markets-need-regulation/) pertains to human milk, but would likely be applicable to harpy eggs and dryad leaves as well. It turns out that there is a thriving market for human milk. Of course, the job category of *[wet nurse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_nurse)* is nothing new. The wealthy nobility have been farming their peasants for milk for ages. In modern times, wet nursing per se is uncommon, but women often pump and donate milk for use by NICU babies.

There is a thriving market for human milk. [Body builders](https://www.health.com/nutrition/bodybuilders-drinking-breast-milk) drink it. There are many, more or less [dubious claims](https://www.babygaga.com/15-reasons-everyone-should-be-drinking-breastmilk/) about its benefits.

Long and short of it: *one harpy omelette comin' up!*

(For your extra question: products made from wool would fall under FTC jurisdiction & its [Wool Products Labelling Act](https://www.ftc.gov/node/119457).)

Answer (score 1):

If such things have long been part of the culture, then the FDA in your world would have dealt with them long ago.

If they have suddenly appeared...then you have a very long regulatory road to go down. Proving that a new substance is safe is a long and complex process.

Having vegetable material of unknown origin and questionable chemistry in anything you sell is a huge red flag. This is exactly what various Chinese Traditional Medicine vendors get in trouble for.

Also -- cannibalism is a bit of an 'ewwww' for anyone.